# make a list of class attributes in the order they appear

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a `tuple` of `classes` in the following format:

```
In: print(my_tuple)

Out: (class_name(c=1, b=2, a=3),class_name(c=4, b=5, a=6),class_name(c=7, b=8, a=9))
```

How can I make a `list` of the `tuple`'s `classes` atributes, in the same order that those attributes appear?

The result should be:

```
In: print(my_list)

Out: [c, b, a]
```

I've got this code, but the resulting list comes sorted in alphabetical order: (All classes attributes are standardized, so I can use the first class as a model)

```
attributes = inspect.getmembers(class_name[0], lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
my_list = [a[0] for a in attributes if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))]
```

Comment: If your tuple had `(class_name(a=1, b=2, c=3),class_name(c=4, b=5, a=6),class_name(c=7, b=8, a=9))`, would you still want `[c, b, a]` as the output for `my_list`?

Comment: the attributes sequence are standard, for all N `classes`, so I can get the attributes of the first `class`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspect.getfullargspec`:

```py
In [41]: class Test:
    ...:     def __init__(self, c=1, b=2, a=3):
    ...:         pass
    ...:

In [42]: inspect.getfullargspec(Test)
Out[42]: FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'c', 'b', 'a'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(1, 2, 3), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

In [43]: inspect.getfullargspec(Test).args
Out[43]: ['self', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

EDIT:

If you're dealing with an instance of a class, you can call it on the `type` instead of the instance itself like so:

```py
In [62]: t=Test()

In [63]: inspect.getfullargspec(t)  # Throws TypeError

In [64]: inspect.getfullargspec(type(t))  # Call on type
Out[64]: FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'c', 'b', 'a'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(1, 2, 3, 4), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Comment: It works for the class you wrote. For some reason, for the `tuple` of `classes` I have, it is getting a `TypeError: unsupported callable`. `is not a callable object` I have imported `inspect` by the way.

Comment: @DanielArges can you iterate over the classes in your tuple then/

Comment: I just need to access the first class arguments, because they are standard for all classes. When I use `inspect.getfullargspec(my_tuple[0]).args` I get this message of being unsupporte callable.

Comment: @DanielArges, do `inspect.getfullargspec(type(my_tuple[0]))`

Comment: `In: print(inspect.getfullargspec(type(my_tuple[0])))`

`Out: FullArgSpec(args=['iterable'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=((),), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})`